# Symfony, how show normal name of object not enetity number

Tags: symfony, orm, entity, sonata-admin, sonata

I have problem with name of objects. In symfony 4, sonata admin.
When create field autocomplete with result from other enitity i got number of this object enitity, why i dont get normal name witch is saved in database ?

```
                    ->add('child', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [ 
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'multiple' => 'true',
                    ])
```

And there : Edite App\Entity\Invest..... want there normal name. Can anyone help ?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if that's the issue, but `'multiple' => 'true'` isn't a boolean value. It's a string.

Comment: 'multiple' => 'true', is ok :) @MilanG helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing "magic" method `__toString()` in you object class:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

and inside it generate name of you object. So, add it like:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->foo;
}
```

Your function just has to return a string. Use variables you have in your object to generate that string.